# pygame-drum example in mingus gives fluidsynth soundfont.sf2 load error

Tags: python, pygame, fluidsynth

I have downloaded `mingus` and want to run the `pygame-drum` example. I have installed the various dependencies it requires such as `pygame`, `fluidsynth` etc.

I get the following when I run:

```
python pygame-drum.py

fluidsynth: error: Unable to open file "soundfont.sf2" 
fluidsynth: error: Couldn't load soundfont file 
fluidsynth: error: Failed to load SoundFont "soundfont.sf2" 
Couldn't load soundfont soundfont.sf2
```

What is missing in this case and what more do I need to install to make the `pygame-drum` example work?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried apt-get install fluidsynth ?

```
$ sudo apt-get install fluidsynth
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  fluid-soundfont-gm libfluidsynth1 libqt5x11extras5 qsynth
Suggested packages:
  fluid-soundfont-gs timidity jackd
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fluid-soundfont-gm fluidsynth libfluidsynth1 libqt5x11extras5 qsynth
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 210 not upgraded.
```